# R - Why errors are reducing in each LightGBM CV rounds?

Tags: r, lightgbm

I think I made a mistake in implementing a CV in LightGBM in R. As shown by the code below, I perform cross validation with 100 rounds and after I check the errors of each iteration. I cannot understand why the error keeps reducing as the iterations move forward

I was expecting the errors to be constant along the iterations. What I did wrong in my code?

```
#Define which variables should be treated as categorical by the LightGBM algorithm
cat_lgbm = c('Profession', 'Department', 'Floor', 'Profile')

#Define the parameters of the model
params = list(
  objective = "regression",
  metric = "l1", #L1 loss function = MAE
  nthread = 2 #The number of cores of the CPU of my PC
)

model_lgbm_teste = lgb.cv(
    params = params,
    nrounds = 100,
    nfold = 5,
    stratified = FALSE,
    data = train_lgbm,
    verbose = -1, #disable the print of evaluation during training
    categorical_feature = cat_lgbm #Determines which variables are categorical
)

#Check the errors for each iterations
model_lgbm_teste$record_evals$valid$l1

$eval
$eval[[1]]
[1] 13.7251

$eval[[2]]
[1] 12.45701

$eval[[3]]
[1] 11.29761

$eval[[4]]
[1] 10.28184

$eval[[5]]
[1] 9.395479
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior, there is nothing "wrong" in your code.

A LightGBM model is an ordered collection of trees. Each "iteration" adds a tree to the model to attempt to improve the fit to the training data.

The reduction in Mean Absolute Error (MAE) shown in your example is what should be expected...with each additional tree, LightGBM's predictions on the held-out samples in each cross-validation fold are more accurate.

At some point the cross validation errors may stop changing or even start increasing again (as overfitting hurts the generalizability of the trained model), but it's expected that in the beginning iterations, cross-validation error will decrease as additional training iterations are performed.

For more details on this process, see ["Introduction to Boosted Trees" (XGBoost docs)](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/model.html).

Comment: Each `nrounds` iteration is actually adding a new tree? It is a boosting round, right? I thought that each round was an iteration in the k-fold CV. So, if I defined 5 rounds, each round would be the full model (with all trees) being cross-validated

Comment: You are mixing two concepts. In `lgb.cv()` in the R package, `nfold` controls how many cross-validation folds (train-test splits) there are. `nrounds` controls how many boosting rounds to perform in each training.

The results in `$record_evals` contain one entry per round (you should see 100 entries if training made it that far), with the value of any evaluation metrics *averaged* over the 5 folds.